# Why cant a static hashmap for a memoizing function be borrowed as mutable?

Tags: static, rust, lifetime, mutable

I'm trying to create a memoization function in `Rust`. The problem comes when getting a mutable reference for the cache `HashMap`. I'm not still confident with the type system and I'm struggling a bit.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

fn memoize<A, B, F>(f: F, cache: &'static HashMap<A, B>) -> impl Fn(A) -> B
where
    A: Eq + Hash + Copy,
    B: Clone,
    F: Fn(A) -> B,
{
    move |value: A| {
        if !cache.contains_key(&value) {
            cache.insert(value, f(value.clone()));
        }
        let res = cache.get(&value).unwrap();
        res.clone()
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `**cache` as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:12:13
   |
12 |             cache.insert(value, f(value.clone()));
   |             ^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Why cannot a static lifetime parameter be mutable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variable is immutable by default in Rust, therefore you cannot mutate a variable that is not declared as `mut`. The [`'static` lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#the-static-lifetime) does not influence the mutability, but only how long the variable lives.

A [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) *"[...] can be called repeatedly without mutating state."*. And exactly here is the problem. You want to mutate the environment (in this case your `HashMap`).

You have to use a [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) to be able to mutate the environment.

If you use the [Entry API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry), you can simplify your code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

fn memoize<A, B, F>(f: F, cache: &'static mut HashMap<A, B>) -> impl FnMut(A) -> B
where
    A: Eq + Hash + Copy,
    B: Clone,
    F: Fn(A) -> B,
{
    move |value: A| {
        let res = cache.entry(value).or_insert_with(|| f(value));
        res.clone()
    }
}
```

As a sidenote, if you compile your code with `#[feature(nll)]` the error message is actually very good.

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*cache` as mutable, as `Fn` closures cannot mutate their captured variables
  --> src/lib.rs:14:13
   |
14 |             cache.insert(value, f(value.clone()));
   |             ^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
   |
help: consider changing this to accept closures that implement `FnMut`
```

Comment: Well, I was pretty close to it. I actually tried the `mut` modifyer after the static, but even if I read about the `FnMut` I forgot to use it! Thanks!!

Comment: @Netwave I optimized the code a litte bit . Of course you can omit `res` as such and just write `.clone()` at the end of the first closure line: `cache.entry(value).or_insert_with(|| f(value)).clone()`